# controlling order of operations in async redux operations with .then

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm using react with redux and thunk middleware. I want to do one asynchronous request, and then have a bunch of actions .then'd off of it occur in synchronous order.  I am not managing to achieve it.

Here are two ways I've tried:

```
addStudent(name, campusId = undefined, view = 'students') {
        const creatingStudent = axios.post('/api/student', { name: name, campusId: campusId })
            .then(res => {
                return res.data
            })
            .then(student => {
               return store.dispatch(createStudent(student))
            })
            .then(()=> {return store.dispatch(getStudents())})
            .then(()=> {return store.dispatch(changeView(view))})         
            .catch(err => console.log(err))




addStudent(name, campusId = undefined, view = 'students') {
         const creatingStudent = axios.post('/api/student', { name: name, campusId: campusId })
             .then(res => {
                 return res.data
             })
             .then(student => {
                store.dispatch(createStudent(student))
               store.dispatch(getStudents())
                store.dispatch(changeView(view))
             })       
             .catch(err => console.log(err))
     }
```

I want the order:
1) the axios request
2) dispatch createStudent
3) dispatch getStudents
4) dispatch changeView

But I have logging middleware installed and 3 and 4 are always reversed.  Also, particularly with the second option, I occasionally get a fatal error that I think is caused by some other reversal of order, but I can't tell exactly what order, since the application is crashing before it logs.

I also tried chaining the calls to dispatch off of each other, but that doesn't seem to work, probably because they are not returning promises.

Here's my getStudents action creator:

```
export const getStudents = () => {
   return dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/students')
      .then(response => {
        return dispatch(receiveStudents(response.data));
      });
  }
};
```

It makes sense that it is taking a little bit longer since it's hitting the server, but how can I .then off it if store.dispatch doesn't return a promise? What's the right way to do this?

EDIT: This was originally not clearly stated.  I should have been more explicit that my frustration was that changeViews() was dispatched before receiveStudents(), not, as I implied, that changeViews() was dispatched before getStudents().  I did not know when getStudents() was being dispatched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.  One aspect of the way I asked the question was misleading.  I wanted to change the View after I had my students, and I was frustrated that I saw CHANGE_VIEW and then RECEIVE_STUDENTS in my logging middleware.  But that's not the same as saying 3 and 4 are reversed. In fact, 3 and 4 were dispatched in order. I now understand that because getStudents() is itself an asynchronous operation, *dispatching* it will resolve before the asynchronous action completes.  Thus, even though getStudents() and changeView() were dispatched in order, receiveStudents() was dispatched after changeView().  In my case, if I wanted changeView() to be dispatched after receiveStudents(), I needed to .then dispatch(changeView()) within getStudents().

Here's refactored code that accomplishes what I wanted:

```
addStudent(student, view = 'students') {
    const creatingStudent = axios.post('/api/student', student)
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(student => store.dispatch(createStudent(student)))
        .then(()=> store.dispatch(getStudents(view)))      
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}



const getStudents = (view) => {
   return dispatch => {
     axios.get('/api/students')
       .then(res => dispatch(receiveStudents(res.data)))
       .then(()=>dispatch(changeView(view)))
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This conversation helped me a lot when I ran into this issue https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/723.

You should be able to do something like this with axios:

```
axios.all([
  store.dispatch(createStudent(student)),
  store.dispatch(getStudents()),
  store.dispatch(changeView(view))
]).then(() => {
  console.log('I did everything!');
});
```

You can use .then after each dispatch to chain actions. I see that you said you tried, but this setup is pulled straight from the redux-thunk middleware github readme and should work for your case https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk:

```
return dispatch(
      makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My Grandma')
    ).then(() =>
      Promise.all([
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Me')),
        dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('My wife'))
      ])
    ).then(() =>
      dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('Our kids'))
    ).then(() => //Chain another dispatch
      dispatch(getState().myMoney > 42 ?
        withdrawMoney(42) :
        apologize('Me', 'The Sandwich Shop')
      )
    );
```

Comment: hey, I appreciate the help, but I don't know if this idea achieves quite what I wanted -- I may not have been clear.  I don't want store.dispatch(getStudents()) to execute until createStudent is done, and I don't want changeView to execute until getStudents is done.  As I understand the .all command, it will resolve when all promises have been resolved.  I'm still reading the page you sent and trying to figure out whether parts of the discussion are relevant to my case.

Comment: Okay, updated answer to show how to dispatch actions one after another

Comment: At first I was struggling with seeing a difference between that and my first example, but now I see one: the original function in the docs takes dispatch as an argument and uses dispatch instead of store.dispatch to send the actions to the store.  Maybe that is my problem.  Maybe I should have defined an async action creator elsewhere and used addStudent to invoke it.  I will try it and report back.

Comment: ok, I'm reporting back.  I refactored so that my addStudents now calls store.dispatch on a function which is an async action creator, which takes dispatch as an argument and which dispatches getStudents, changeView, etc with dispatch, and not store.dispatch.  changeView still executes before getStudents.  It's as if, in the example, withdrawMoney were executing before making a sandwich for the kids.  I need to produce a minimum reproducible example I know -- it just feels overwhelming with a database, etc., but if you or anyone else is still engaged I'll do it.

Comment: I think I understand now; perhaps I should have been more explicit about *what* was happening out of order.  My intention was to wait till I had the students, then change the view.  I was frustrated when I saw that changeView() got dispatched, then *receiveStudents()* got dispatched, and that I was changing my view before my had my students.  But I think I see now that the dispatch of *getStudents()* can be resolved, and the .then chain can move on to dispatching changeView() before the axios requests completes and *receiveStudents* is dispatched, updating the state.